# Testing to see if view exists, but my method returns false - it should return true

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, view

I have a method `viewExists` to see check whether I have a view in my database. Currently I do, but my method doesn't seem to know that, as it keeps returning false.

```
public static boolean viewExists(Connection conn, String view) throws SQLException {        
        boolean exists = false;
        try {
            ResultSet rs = conn.getMetaData().getTables(null, null, view, new String[] {"VIEW"});
                if (rs.next()) {
                    String name = rs.getString("TABLE_NAME");
                    if (name != null && name.contentEquals(view)) {
                        exists = true;
                    }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return exists;
    }
```

The whole point of this is to see if the view exists, and if it does, I drop it and create a new one.

I am pretty new to JDBC, and so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to drop & create a view from within your application? I would suggest using a separate tool to create schemas and views, e.g. [flyway](https://flywaydb.org/).

Comment: It's part of a project we have for uni

Comment: Are you forced to do it from within the application? If not: my initial stance holds. If yes: talk to your professor/supervisor, convince him that a separate tool is better and then my initial stance holds.

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Are there any runtime errors? You have it inside a trycatch so if it fails in the try then it'll always return false.  Go back to the basics and step through the code.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? In Postgres you could simply use `drop view if exists ...` then `create view`

Answer (score 0):

As the comment by Turing86 said, doing dynamic table creation in raw JDBC like this is... reinventing a wheel, and you probably shouldn't do that.

Whilst in SQL db names are case insensitive, when working with JDBC metadata they are not, and the casing you need rather annoyingly depends on DB engine. Most likely you want 'view' and not 'VIEW' or 'table_name' and not TABLE_NAME.

As a separate note, this is really silly error handling; exceptions contain 4 bits of info (type, message, trace, and cause), and you're chucking out 3 of the 4 facts, dumping the remaining info someplace where it'll be drowned out by the noise, and then you return a wrong answer. Horrible. Just delete the try block and add `throws SQLException` to your code: It is entirely reasonable for a method that checks if a table exists, to throw that (and keep adding `throws` clauses all the way up to main, unless you actually have some code to deal with exceptions, and 'print them' or 'log them' or 'ignore them' is not handling it).

I'd also print each result as it comes in, just in case 'VIEW' is right but 'TABLE_NAME' is not.

If you can't figure it out, remove VIEW and just make it null, in which case you get everything, which is too much, but print the relevant sections and you'll figure out the right name from there, for your DB engine.